# Percentage of crash-free sessions in Crashlytics is wrong

Tags: ios, crash, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am an iOS developer, and recently I try to find a tool to track crashes in our project.

- After I integrated **Crashlytics** in my demo, I forced the demo to
  crash for some times and check if the data in Crashlytics is correct.
- But then I am confused by the data on the dashboard because the
  percentage of 'CRASH-FREE SESSIONS' is always '<1%', while the total
  number of crashes is 65.
- Even I launch my demo and then kill it without crash it for several
  time, the '<1%' doesn't change.

Is it a bug of Crashlytics?

I have sent 3 email to support@fabric.io, but did not get any reply. I don't know what is going on here.

Comment: Todd from Fabric here. Check out https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html and look at the output. If you don't see any errors related to Fabric in the output you should be good to go! :)

Comment: Thanks Todd. Of course I have missed the former output, and now I don't see any errors in several new testing. It seems that the numbers of crashes and affected users are correct, so I believe that it's ok for Fabric to collect all the crash reports. But the percentage of 'CRASH-FREE SESSIONS' makes no sense evidently. I can do some testings with TestFlight to simulate Product Environment, and if it works, it seems to be a bug in Testing Environment.

Comment: Yes, crashes that happen while connected to the simulator don't appear in your dashboard but sometimes get counted in the crash-free sessions stream. Launch crashes can be reported into the crash-free number as well and then not be reported to your dashboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your users. I had the same problem because I was testing it within my simulator and my iOS device, fabric is a service made by google. It's impossible to find a bug like that-- rest assured. Submit your app. Let your users use it, the actual result will come in a week

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try :)

Comment: Thank me by clicking the green check mark, if I helped